GKE Autopilot Cluster: HPA shows 'unschedulable pod' and won't scale cluster resources
I have a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster in Autopilot mode. However, when the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) needs to scale, I receive a message indicating "unschedulable pod" and the cluster does not automatically increase its resources.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Disabled the policy compute.disableSerialPortLogging at the organization level: Navigated to Organization policies -> Disable VM serial port logging to Stackdriver -> Overrode the parent's policy and created a rule "Not enforced"
Enabled the serial port logging in the project metadata.

Despite these changes, the issue persists. I am unsure if I have correctly implemented these steps or if there are additional configurations required.

If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Ideally Autopilot comes with NAP and CA enabled. However, an interactive playbook option that is present in the cloud monitoring section would help to resolve the issue.
Also, it would be helpful if you post the error message here along with the pod YAML file.
